# When using Counter in Python how would I change the number of occurrences in a dictionary from numbers to asterisks(*)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am counting occurences of names and want to display them with how often they occured:

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["Bob", "Bob", "Sally", "Tom", "Bob", 
        "Tom", "Evan", "Sally", "Evan", "Evan"]

c = Counter(data)

for key, value in c.items():
    print(key + "\t      " + str(value))
```

this gives me

```
Bob           3
Sally         2
Tom           2
Evan          3
```

But I want

```
Bob           ***
Sally         **
Tom           **
Evan          ***
```

How to do it?

Comment: ``str(value)`` => ``'*' * value``

Comment: Counter creates a dictionary and I also fixed the other issues, my apologies

Comment: Thank you @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Thank you very much this helped